# iptables: allow everything that aims towards nginx

Tags: nginx, iptables

my router has a port forwarding from port 80 to 8080 to a linux server. On port 8080 there is nginx listening and acting as a reverse proxy. Nginx can redirect to another port on the same machine. (port 8080 redirects to another web interface on the server running on port 9000)

Now I want to setup iptables on the server but would like to accept everything that wants to reach Nginx. Can iptables still detect that the original destination port was 80 and allow every port redirect that is following (80 -> 8080 -> 9000)? Or do I have to add 8080 to iptables? Or even 9000?

Thank you!

Comment: Most likely only `8080`, unless you have traffics to `lo` blocked (in that case `9000` needs to be an exception I guess). `80` is irrelevant to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iptables on the server can't see the original port as 80, as it is receiving it as port 8080 because the router modified the packet when it was being forwarded. You tell iptables on the server to accept traffic for port 8080.

You would also want iptables to accept connection on port 9000 on local host. You most likely don't need to do anything here as there is typically a rule allowing anything to/from localhost. This is because a proxy terminates the incoming connection and sets up a second connection from itself to the target.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Localhost is never blocked, so I should be fine allowing port 8080.